# Pyenv: no such command `version-name'

Tags: ubuntu, virtualenv, zsh, pyenv

Whenever I launch a new terminal, I receive this error:

```
~/.pyenv/bin/pyenv: line 36: ./bin/readlink: No such file or directory
pyenv: no such command `version-name'
```

I opened the file in the text editor, and line 36 have this command:

```
  resolve_link() {
    $READLINK "$1"
  }
```

I've searched on Google, but it seems nobody has had the same problem before.

Comment: Can you add `export PYENV_DEBUG=1` to ~/.zshenv? That will be loaded before anything else and make pyenv print a bunch of debug output.

Answer (score 1):

Solved! The problem was related to the Ubuntu settings in the Windows Terminal, the root path was wrong and with that it didn't properly load the pyenv settings